# What is the point of getEl() in extjs4

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a listener that is called when a tab is activated.

```
, listeners: {
     activate: function(tab){
         var first = tab.down('input'),                 // will be null
             firstEl = tab.getEl().down('input');       // will contain first input element
```

I'm not having a lot of luck understanding the relationship between tab and tab.getEl().  If this was jquery, $(tab) would give me a jquery element which would largely expand on my set of options.  extjs seems to be almost backwards in this regards, or at least more complicated.

I'm trying to understand when and why I need `getEl()` so that it is less of a development crapshoot about what will and won't work.  In other places I do things like:

```
showFieldHelpOnBlur = function(ctrl) {
    ctrl.up('form').down('#helptext').update("");
}
```

without the getEl().  In this case **form** is an element tag just like **input** (above), but I don't need the getEl() before I use it.  In general the two sets of functionality that share the same names but don't work the same are frustrating, and the docs don't seem to give any clue as to why there are multiple methods with the same names that do different things, or do similar things in a different way.

Found some similar issues with `focus()`, but those might make more sense if I just understood why are there are 2 seemingly parallel sets of methods for what are essentially DOM elements wrapped in additional functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think at the core of your confusion is how you approach the development using ExtJS vs JQuery.

JQuery is all about DOM manipulation and low level API. ExtJS approach is very different, it wants you to think of your page structure as a hierarchy of ExtJS components that are responsible for rendering appropriate HTML. So ExtJS is essentially saying: "Don't worry about html, we'll take care of it - you focus on the larger components, layouts, events, etc. "

You will say "Whoa Nelly! What do you mean don't worry about html? I want control!" And ExtJS will respond OK - we have a wrapper object called `Element` (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element) you can use it to do DOM manipulation just like you are used to with JQuery .. but be cautious. Because if you manage your own HTML we can't be responsible for what happens to your layouts and components that are not managed by the framework.

My advice is this - when in Rome do like Romans do :)

If you are going to be using ExtJS to build apps - embrace the way ExtJS is designed to work. Learn the different layout mechanics and numerous component types available to you out of the box. Use the MVC development pattern to beautifully organize your code. Use the examples to your advantage. Study the architecture and component guides - these are very useful. Understanding ComponentQuery class is a must (all those up/down methods and query).

At the end, when you have gained comfort using ExtJS components and their style of development you will be very efficient at building your UI compositions and can build much more complex applications than before.

Good Luck!

Pro Tip: Do yourself a favor and get Illuminations for Developers plugin for Firebug - it will open your eyes to see things using component structure rather than HTML elements.

Comment: In the code above, I'm not trying to modify the DOM, I'm just trying to set the focus to the field.  Reading what you said caused me to try `tab.down('field')` which did not return null.  How was I to know that  `field` was a valid selector for any kind of field?  It's the xtype/alias for field/Base, but all the derived fields have their own alias and there is nothing in the docs (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) to indicate you can use any partial base class name to do the lookup.

Comment: My question was driven more by WHY do I sometimes have to use `getEl()` to get something done, why is there this dual path of functionality where x doesn't always work, so you have to guess if you should crack out the `getEl()` so you can actually get to the element to set the focus.  I will try illuminations though.

Comment: The difference is split 3 ways : a Component vs Element vs actual DOM element and their respective APIs that are exposed to you. When dealing with Components you use tools like Component Query and set of API that is exposed through the hierarchy of inherited properties, behaviors, and events. Underneath that you can get under the skin of components and operate at the HTML Element wrapper level. This set of API will closely match the actual DOM API but will add it's own set of methods and events. getEl() method will give you that Element object to operate on. el.dom exposes the actual DOM api.

Comment: Depending on how you write you code you will use one or all of these APIs. I prefer to operate on the highest level of the Component API and extend ootb components to add specific functionality. In rare cases where functionality or behavior of HTML elements is not exposed through higher level API I will go ahead and dig into the Element level and operate there.